# How to clear the text field when clicked on "clear" button in template-driven form in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

i am trying to make a basic login form with two input fields and a "clear" button which should blank the input field on click.How to do that ?

i know how to do it in reactive forms using reset() but i don't know how to do in template-driven form.

```js
<form>
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input   name="username" ngModel #name="ngModel" required minlength="4" maxlength="10" appForbiddenName="jedii" type="text">
   <div *ngIf="name.touched && !name.valid">
     <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">username is mandatory</div>
     <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">username must be of min 4 characters</div>
     <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">username cannot be jedii</div>
   </div> 
  <br><br>
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="password" required>
</form>
<br>
<button>Login</button>
<br>
<br>
<button>Clear</button>
```

i expect that text field should be reset to blank but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ngForm attribute.

[click to guide](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)

example:

```html
<form #testForm="ngForm">
</form>
<button (click)="testForm.reset()">Clear</button>
```

edit: should be resetForm(). you can read guide. thanks

edit: final solution

```html
 <form #testForm="ngForm">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input name="username"
               ngModel
               #name="ngModel"
               required
               minlength="4"
               maxlength="10"
               type="text">

        <br><br>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password"
               ngModel
               name="password"
               #password="ngModel"
               required>
      </form>
      <br>
      <button>Login</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button (click)="testForm.resetForm()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: hey thanks. but it only clears the username field. can you help me how to clear the password filed along the username field.

Comment: @JP2_7 add this attributes to your password input ->       ngModel
               name="password"
               #password="ngModel"

Comment: woah it worked.thanks.how did you learn angular ? any tips for beginner ?

Comment: i am happy to help you. i've been working on angular since angularjs and angular 2. I suggest you follow this youtube channel.  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCm9iiIfgmVODUJxINecHQkA and this https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSJbGtTlrDami-tDGPUV9-w @JP2_7

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case like this, you can even use `type=reset`

```
<form>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="password"><br>
    <button type="reset">Clear</button><br>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i was wrong.its resetted. this is clear way for solution

Comment: @EmreHIZLI AFAIK This has problems only when using custom form elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form template reference like

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(login)" #login="ngForm">
```

and in .ts file you can use it like

```
onSubmit(login: ngForm) {
  login.resetForm();
}
```